# Непонятный символ в PhpStorm , Красный круг внутри черный, что он означает?

Tags: phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, intelij

Непонятный символ в PhpStorm, предполагаю что он используется и в других intellij IDE редакторах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что оно означает ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-icons

Это отключенная точка останова для отладки(disabled line breakpoint).